# Autocomplete and resolve in Eclipse/Cevelop for mongocxx and bsoncxx libraries

Tags: c++, eclipse, mongodb, cevelop

I'm using mongocxx and bsoncxx libraries in latest Cevelop (Eclipse based) IDE.

Sample code:

```
bsoncxx::builder::basic::document builder {}; // no red lines
// fill the doc here ...
bsoncxx::document::value document = builder.extract(); // can't resolve the type nor builder.extract()
```

It does what it needs to, it compiles without errors, runs fine, but I can't get the IDE to resolve all of the classes (for autocomplete etc). `bsoncxx::builder::basic::document` is clickable, goes to the right header file, so at least something is working fine, but `Type 'bsoncxx::document::value' could not be resolved`.

If I look at the declarations in header files from the library where they should come from

```
class document : public sub_document { ... }
class BSONCXX_API value { ... }
```

Is the parser in my IDE not good enough to parse the library or is there a way to make it work? Is that "BSONCXX_API" throwing off the parser, because *document* works fine, but not *value*?